# Sorting out similar images

Tags: python, performance

I'm creating a data set to be used for a machine learning application. To do this I use my webcam to record videos at 1 frame per minute and did this for a few days.

I then created a program to extract these frames (in gray scale) to create my data set and let it run over the weekend.

After I noticed that not all my videos were set to 1 frame per minute (I assume that some were set to 60 frames per second). My data set is now saturated with extremely similar images (I believe this will cause issues when trying to train my ML application) and because of this I have decided to try to filter out similar images.

The small python script I've written to do this compare images and if they are "similar" then they are moved to a folder that I'll delete after. The amount of files that this script has to compare is very large and I'm afraid that it'll start slowing down to a crawl.

Would you be able to help review my code and offer any suggestions to optimize the performance of it. Thanks in advance.

I think the place that would benefit from the greatest improvement is how I choose to compare two images. To determine if an image is similar I add up the differences in pixels between this image and each "unique" image I've currently found. If this is value is less than a threshold I have set (15 million) than I label the image as similar and move it if not I add it to the "unique" list.

```
#import 3rd party Lib
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import traceback
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pickle
import hashlib
import time

def Compare(dirTarget, dirDest):

    compareFiles = []

    sourceFileList = [f for f in listdir(dirTarget) if isfile(join(dirTarget, f))]
    print("Files Read from HD")
    i = 0

    startT = time.time()
    while len(sourceFileList) > 0:

        file = sourceFileList.pop()
        targetImage = cv2.imread(dirTarget + file,0)

        isSimilar = False

        for compareImage in compareFiles:
            deltaArr = np.absolute(np.subtract(targetImage, compareImage))
            dist = round(sum(map(sum, deltaArr))/1000000,0)

            if dist < 15:
                isSimilar = True
                continue

        if isSimilar:
            os.rename(dirTarget + file, dirDest + file)
        else:
            compareFiles.append(targetImage)

        if i == 100:
            i = 0
            endT = time.time()
            difference = int(endT - startT)
            startT = endT
            print("Unsimilar: " + str(len(compareFiles)) +
                  " Left: " + str(len(sourceFileList)) +
                  " Time: " + str(difference))
        else:
            i += 1



hashedUniqueList = list()

dir1 = "Superevised Set\One\\"
dir0 = "Superevised Set\Zero\\"

destdir1 = "ToDel\One\\"
destdir0 = "ToDel\Zero\\"

dirTarget = dir1
dirDest = destdir1
```

The reason I choose 15 million as my threshold is because I did a quick sampling of how similar an image was to a subset of images and I got the following distribution. This is roughly 0.6% of my data. Do you think this number should be higher or (I doubt) lower.

```
Delta   Count
11  1
12  16
13  32
14  112
15  306
16  436
17  995
18  1756
19  980
20  1195
21  822
22  651
23  1067
24  1656
25  4561
26  4676
27  3105
28  4008
29  2125
30  3587
31  4694
32  3557
33  2136
34  1491
35  1969
36  794
37  949
38  286
39  801
40  569
41  425
42  471
43  225
44  241
45  59
46  367
47  190
48  146
49  459
50  220
51  84
52  734
53  1100
54  257
55  521
56  1071
57  296
58  928
59  1624
60  764
61  1001
62  1792
63  1884
64  1496
65  4074
66  6557
67  11
```

Comment: If this is a real problem you have - Do the files still have the original created date? if so, you'll probably get more accurate and much faster results by sorting by date, then running through the list and deleting images that are within 60seconds of the previous one.

Comment: The created dates are from when I extracted the frames. My application has multiple files with the same creation date but I named my files "timestamp + incremental number" where incremental number was used when multiple frames were able to be extracted during the same timestamp. The problem is that I don't know if the difference between neighboring files (files extracted one after the other) is 1/60 of a second or 60 seconds (or another value). Not all videos had the same frame rate so I can't just take groups of 60 files and delete 59 of them.

Comment: Are you opposed to using common libraries that are **dedicated** to finding similar images? Something like [image-match](https://github.com/EdjoLabs/image-match)?

Comment: No I am not. Other than image-match which would you recommend for performance? And thank you for the link.

Comment: @Mandelbrotter I don't have personal recommendations, mostly since I haven't used these tools personally. However, I would recommend going through a list of [search results](https://github.com/search?q=image+duplication).